# Build exterior stairs in onedirection with a total rise of 13' with a mid landing

Tags: wood

Build an exterior staircase with a mid landing with a total rise of 13'

Comment: Welcome to DIY.   Some details might help us answer your question.  This question is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: But I don't need such a staircase. Why should I build one?

Comment: What are you looking for? Recommended materials? Design advice? Code requirements? Where in the world (codes differ)? Need more details.

Comment: In my experience all stairs go in two directions at a minimum

Answer (score 1):

Can you? Yes, but code allows maximum rise of 12’ without a landing and the landing needs to be a minimum of 36” in the direction of travel. (Stair needs to be a minimum of 36” wide ABOVE the handrail.) See IRC R311.5.